# Adding a child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 views, `ParentViewController` and `ChildViewController`; I want to nest `ChildViewController` inside `ParentViewController`. I have designed `ParentViewController` and `ChildViewController` in Storyboard. `ParentViewController.m` contains the logic for the parent and `ChildViewController.m` contains the logic for the child. In `ParentViewController.m` I add the child like so:

```
 ChildViewController *childVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildSBI"];
 [self addChildViewController:childVC];
```

My Question: How can I position `childVC` within `ParentViewController` (i.e. set it's origin).

It seems like I want to do something like the following:

1. Alloc init child
2. Call (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view on the view of the child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I position childVC within ParentViewController (i.e. set it's origin).

Remember that a view *controller* doesn't have an origin -- only its view does. To make a view controller's content appear on screen, you need a view to draw it in. You *can* have one view controller's view appear in another view controller's view hierarchy, and it's quite easy to do with storyboards.

To set up a parent/child relationship between view controllers in a storyboard, do the following:

- Add a container view to the parent view controller's view hierarchy.
- Drag an "embed" segue from that container view to the child view controller.
- You can use the usual `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method to let the parent controller pass data to the child.

You can also set things up programmatically, if you prefer, and the code you've got is a good start:

```
ChildViewController *childVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildSBI"];
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
```

After that, your parent view controller should set the child's view's position and add it to the parent's view, like this:

```
UIView *childView = childVC.view;
childView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 300, 100, 100); //use whatever coordinates you want
[self.view addSubview:childView];
```

There's a lot more detail in [Creating Custom Container Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html), but the basic answer to your question is that the container controller should set the size and position of the contained controller's view.

Comment: thanks for the tips. So upon instantiation of the parent will prepareForSegue automatically be called? I was planning on calling addChildViewController in viewDidLoad as the childview will always be present

Comment: @Apollo Yes, if you use the embed segue, the child view controller will be instantiated and `-prepareForSegue:sender:` will be called when the parent controller loads its view.

Comment: ahh. Thanks for the very detailed answer and updated programmatic solution. Very helpful my friend.